# I am trying to write my stored input into a text element on the webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jquery-selectors

I am trying to write an extension that will search the webpage for a specific text element and write my const into it.

Some additional context: The process flow is essentially;

1. Pop up prompts user to provide input
2. User provides input and presses submit
3. Some changes are made to the input and it is stored as 'data'
4. Extension then searches webpage for specific text element called 'title'
5. Extension then writes my 'data' const to this text element.

Here is what I have at the moment - I cannot get this to write. Not sure if it is not identifying the element or not writing correctly.

```js
const titleInput = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="title"], textarea[name="title"]')[0];
if (titleInput.value[0]) {
  titleInput.value = titleWithoutQuotes;
} else {
  console.error('Title input field not found');
}
```

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML

Comment: `if (titleInput && titleInput.value) {`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is off

```
const titleInputs = document
  .querySelectorAll('input[name="title"], textarea[name="title"]'); // get any name=title input or textarea
if (titleInputs.length > 0) {
  titleInputs[0].value = titleWithoutQuotes;
} else {
  console.error('Title input field not found');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax fix. Still no luck, I cannot get this to write. I am specifically trying to write to the Etsy new listing page. I've been at this for like 8 hours and just can't get it.